# Infinite sample space of Ω

Tags: probability, infinity

I'm trying to think of an example of a probability space (Ω,β,p) such that Ω is an infinite sample space but |β| < ∞, or  to prove that no such a probability space can exist.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Ω any infinite set and β = {Ω,∅}, with p(Ω) = 1 and p(∅) = 0.